# How does gmail know the brand of computer device

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, javascript

Watching the currently logged in devices in a google account I saw my PC listed with its brand: DELL-BRANDNAME (the brand name written on PC body). I thought it is not possible to get this information through JavaScript so chrome is giving this information to google ?

EDIT:
By computer name I mean the brand the company that manufactured the computer has assigned to it not the hostname as the hostname is very deifferent from this

you can see the same situation here: https://www.reddit.com/r/privacy/comments/iv25xs/google_knows_my_computers_model/

Comment: Are you logged in to Chrome?

Comment: it is possible to get the hostname via JS.

Comment: @FrankThomas Got any more info on that? I don’t see how that would be possible without relying on WebRTC hacks and whatnot.

Comment: (Posting as a comment because I'm pretty sure none of this is used by Google, so it doesn't answer OP's question) It's possible to query the graphics driver via JS ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WEBGL_debug_renderer_info).  Browsers are slowly pulling support for browser fingerprinting.  Absent anti-fingerprinting, this is enough to [identify an iOS model](https://github.com/joyqi/mobile-device-js/blob/master/device.js), since every iOS model uses a different renderer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concluded that chrome sends this information to google so when I tried from microsoft edge I didn't see the device model. I found on chrome privacy page that chrome collects this information: https://www.google.com/chrome/privacy/whitepaper.html

> Users can share phone numbers and text between their devices (mobile or desktop) when they are signed-in to Chrome. The transferred data is encrypted during transit and Google cannot read or store the content. To let users select the device to share with, Chrome collects the following information about devices on which a user is signed-in and stores that in the user's Google account: device manufacturer, model number, Chrome version, OS, and device type.

Comment: I'll note that Google also documents this on https://policies.google.com/privacy under "Your apps, browsers & devices."

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you are seeing the semi-random name assigned to your computer's operating system upon initialization. You can confirm this (and change it to your liking) by editing the PC name in system properties, then revisiting the location previous displaying the information of concern.

Comment: please see edit

Answer (score -1):

The browser reads your os' hostname and makes it available in the user agent string (don't quote me on that), which in turn is set on OS install and detected from hardware.

On windows, you can see the hostname when right-clicking > Properties on Computer. For linux/mac, open a terminal and it's "youruser@hostname: $" if running bash or simply run `$ hostname`).

Comment: please see edit

Comment: The user agent string does of course _not_ contain the hostname. It identifies the browser, not the machine the browser is running on.